# How to use CComSafeArray to obtain SAFEARRAY data

Tags: visual-c++, com

I don't know why below command of "HRESULT hr=cElement.Attach(*saData);" did not work. I like to apply the learning to retrieve a large data defined by "SAFEARRAY". thank you.

```
  #include "atlsafe.h"
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;


  void CreateSafeArray(SAFEARRAY **saData)
  {

  SAFEARRAYBOUND Bound;
  Bound.lLbound = 0;
  Bound.cElements = 10;

  *saData = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 1, &Bound);

  short HUGEP * pData = NULL;
  HRESULT hr = SafeArrayAccessData(*saData, (void HUGEP * FAR *)&pData);
  if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
      {
         for (short i = 0; i <(short) Bound.cElements; ++i)
         {
             pData[i]=i;
         }
         SafeArrayUnaccessData(*saData);    
      }
   }

  int main(void)
  {
      // Create SafeAarray
      SAFEARRAY **saData=new SAFEARRAY*;
      CreateSafeArray(&*saData);

      // access SafeArray by CComSafeArray
      CComSafeArray <short> cElement;
      HRESULT hr=cElement.Attach(*saData);  

      SafeArrayDestroy(*saData);
  }
```

Comment: Attach() has a runtime check to verify that the array you pass matches the CComSafeArray type argument.  It doesn't, the array contains variants and not shorts.  I'm fairly sure you meant SafeArrayCreate(VT_I2, 1, &Bound) to create an array of shorts instead of variants.  If not then you have to fix the element assignment as well.

Comment: Thank Hans. After changing to "CComSafeArray <VARIANT> cElement", there was not more error.